# Firebase: Query filtering in javascript on() events

Tags: firebase

Is there a way to filter down which properties of each child I want to bring back inside of ref.on("value", ...)?

Let's say I have the structure on https://www.firebase.com/docs/data-structure.html, but in addition to name, each user also has a list of every line of chat he has produced. How can I bring back only the name?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: As of Firebase 2.0, you can now [query based on fields](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries).

There isn't currently a way to pick data out of a path (i.e. filter which fields you get back). The easiest solution here is to store the data in different paths. It greatly simplifies the process.

```
users/
users/names/fred/first
users/chat_history/fred/...
```

Another useful approach, particularly when you're going to be using a lot of subsets (e.g. friends list, members of a group, et al) is to use an index.

```
user_index/group_1/fred
user_index/group_1/mary
user_index/group_2/...

users/fred/name
users/fred/chat_history
```

Then you can access the data with something like this:

```
var fb = new Firebase(INSTANCE);
fb.child('user_index').on('child_added', function(ss) {
   fb.child('users/'+ss.name()+'/name').once('value', function(nameSnapshot) {
      var userName = nameSnapshot.val();
   });
});
```